# glowing meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

From the surface of the following sentences, it is achieved that the meaning of the "glowing" is brilliant but in the dictionaries, it is defined like this:

[full of enthusiastic praise](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/glowing)

They may change color with changing light conditions and cloud cover, **glowing** pink or gold in the morning or evening light.

Comment: You should fix the typo- “glowing,” not “growing.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/glow

> to produce a continuous light and sometimes heat

That’s the definition you’re looking for. The present participle of “to glow” is “glowing” and is being used as an adjective here.